# split value not getting in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have two jsp.one is user.jsp.In that jsp i am getting the record from the database and append space between the two records.for ex: ab9898329379 ab989832937937.The code for user.jsp is as follows.

```
String  data ="";
   ResultSet  rs = st.executeQuery(query);
           while(rs.next())
                {


               data += rs.getString("user_registeration_code")+" " ;
               System.out.println("-------a------"+data);
                }
```

secondjsp is sys.jsp.In that i have used the ajax and getting the result of the above jsp in response.the code of the sys.jsp is as follows.

```
function showEmp(emp_value)
{ 

    var fname = document.getElementById("txtfirstname").value;
    alert(fname);
    var lname = document.getElementById("txtlastname").value;
    alert(lname);
        if(document.getElementById("txtmobileno").value!="")
        {
            alert("1");
 xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp==null)
 {alert("2");
 alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
 return;
 }
var url="getuser.jsp";
url=url+"?emp_id="+emp_value+"&firstname="+fname+"&lastname="+lname;

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged; 
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);

        }
        else
        {
                 alert("Please Select Employee Id");
        }
}

function stateChanged() 
{ 

        document.getElementById("txtfirstname").value ="";
        document.getElementById("txtmobileno").value ="";
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
 { 




    var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText; 

 var strar = showdata.split(" ");

  alert(strar[0]);
  } 
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
var xmlHttp=null;
try
 {
 // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
 xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
catch (e)
 {
 //Internet Explorer
 try
  {
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
 catch (e)
  {
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 }
return xmlHttp;
}
```

i am not getting the expected result like strar[0]=ab9898329379,strar[1]=ab989832937937.
please help.
Thanks in advance 
Rushang

Comment: i am getting the number of result is 2 but not getting the value.

Comment: so you get value as 2 when you type strar[0] ?

Comment: no when i am writing  alert(strar).i am getting ,,,,2.
i am not getting anything when i will right strar[0]

Comment: i used that code but i am getting alert as 2.I am not getting the value.

Comment: try doing strar(0)[1]

Comment: can you please tell me some other solution?

Comment: i found the solution.now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop to get values

```
for (var i = 0; i < strar .length; i++) {
   alert(strar[i]);
}
```

Comment: hi i got strar.length = 1 so is it a problem over thr??

Comment: @rushangpatel what was solution?

Comment: out.println(data).By that i got the value.